# How to handle user interaction with new Bluetooth prompt in iOS13?

Tags: xamarin.forms, bluetooth, xamarin.ios

"There’s a new key for the Info.plist file: *NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription*, which you can use to explain how and why your app uses Bluetooth. In contrast to the existing *NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription*, the new description will be shown as part of the new pop-up, and also in the Settings app on the Bluetooth Privacy screens."

After updating to iOS 13, our app experienced crashes, as I'm sure many did. Our problem was due to not including the newly required bluetooth key in the Xamarin.iOS projects Info.plist file.

However after adding this upon loading the first "action" that occurs is presenting the user with the new Bluetooth access prompt.

We aren't clearly seeing how to capture the response to this prompt. In-fact after this prompt is interacted with the app has no "return" point as it were. Can't quite find a break-point for the prompt interaction / result handling and our app never returns from the prompt. It's running but the next "action" to occur never happens.

So- how to capture/handle user's interaction with the new Bluetooth prompt in iOS 13?

NOTE*: To be absolutely transparent - our application doesn't initialize any instance of *CBCentralManager* rather it takes advantage of a native framework that itself utilizes Bluetooth LE internally (out of our control).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our case might be quite unique but for those experiencing this implement `CBCentralManager` and utilize its `UpdatedState` method to capture user interaction with the newly presented Bluetooth dialogue.

Initialization called in page creation of our Apps MainPage

```
BleManager = new BluetoothManager();
```

Class

```
using System;
using CoreBluetooth;

namespace MyApp.iOS.Classes
{
    public class BluetoothManager
    {
        public CBCentralManager CentralBleManager
        {
            get { return this.bleCntrlMgr; }
        }
        protected CBCentralManager bleCntrlMgr;
        protected CBCentralManagerDelegate bleMgrDel;

        public BluetoothManager()
        {
            this.bleCntrlMgr = new CoreBluetooth.CBCentralManager();
            this.bleCntrlMgr.UpdatedState += BleMgr_UpdatedState;
        }

        private void BleMgr_UpdatedState(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("UpdatedState: {0}", bleCntrlMgr.State);
            if (bleCntrlMgr.State == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn
                || bleCntrlMgr.State == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOff
                || bleCntrlMgr.State == CBCentralManagerState.Resetting
                || bleCntrlMgr.State == CBCentralManagerState.Unauthorized
                || bleCntrlMgr.State == CBCentralManagerState.Unsupported)
            {
                /* return point */
                // i.e.: CallMethod();
            }
            else if (bleCntrlMgr.State == CBCentralManagerState.Unknown)
            {
                /* <-- request access --> */
            }
        }
    }
}
```